# Alpine linux, latest and greatest version of grep

Tags: grep, alpine-linux

I'm looking to install a version of `grep` in an Alpine Docker container thats a similar version to my host OS, v3.3. In hunting around online, I [see the package is available](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/grep) for Alpine. However, on installation, in checking the version v3.1 is installed:

```
bash-4.4# grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.1
...
```

I figured maybe an explicit install is required, and specifying the version may do the trick. Then, I attempt:

```
bash-4.4# apk add --no-cache grep=3.3-r0
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  grep-3.1-r2:
    breaks: world[grep=3.3-r0]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache bash grep=3.3-r0' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Fair enough, I figure some other package explicitly depends on this version of grep. Figure, there's a package info command to hunt that down. After searching the interwebs, I gave this a go:

```
bash-4.4# apk info -a grep
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.b89edf6e.tar.gz: No such file or directory
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.737f7e01.tar.gz: No such file or directory
grep-3.1-r2 description:
Searches input files for lines containing a match to a specified pattern

grep-3.1-r2 webpage:
https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/grep.html

grep-3.1-r2 installed size:
192512

grep-3.1-r2 depends on:
so:libc.musl-x86_64.so.1
so:libpcre.so.1

grep-3.1-r2 provides:
cmd:egrep
cmd:fgrep
cmd:grep

grep-3.1-r2 is required by:

grep-3.1-r2 contains:
bin/grep
bin/egrep
bin/fgrep

grep-3.1-r2 triggers:

grep-3.1-r2 has auto-install rule:

grep-3.1-r2 affects auto-installation of:

grep-3.1-r2 replaces:

grep-3.1-r2 license:
GPL-3.0+
```

No requirements for grep at that version, if I'm reading right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package of `grep` 3.3 is for the [edge](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge) release, *i.e.* the development branch of Alpine Linux. Release 3.9, which you’re using, [has `grep` 3.1](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/main/x86/grep).

If you really want it on your 3.9 system, you could always rebuild it by downloading the relevant [package source](https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/grep?h=master) and [running `abuild` as appropriate](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Creating_an_Alpine_package#Build_the_package).